# Backspace in Sublime Text 3 with spaces indentation

Tags: sublimetext2, settings, sublimetext3

I'm using Sublime Text 3 with spaces indentation (4 space chars for each tab), when I'm pressing the backspace button, it deletes the whole tab (the 4 space chars).

Who can i change it so when I'll press the Backspace button it will delete one space char only?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you have set `"translate_tabs_to_spaces": true` so you want to add `"use_tab_stops": false` to your user `Preferences.sublime-settings` file. Then backspace and tab will operate on spaces, not designated tabstops.

Comment: Please note I edited to make a vital correction which would not have been reflected in any original email notification.